# Real time Traffic on Map View in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am developing an app with Map View. I had implemented Overlays for Map view referencing from 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html 
which works perfectly. Now, I want to show Real-Time Traffic as Google shows. I had also set the map view property `mapView.setTraffic(true);` My App is showing like below,

[image]

Is it all that to be done or is it possible to show like below

[image]

I am looking for some sample, links or tutorials on this. please guide me for the same.

Thanks in advance...

Panache

Comment: Is it possible to show the second Image kind of thing on Androids Map View?

Answer (score 1):

The second image is what is called a 'street view'. Google does have an API for this but you're limited to <del>1000 per viewer</del> Google's quota and its just an image so wouldn't be in a Android Map View.

See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/ for more details.